# What's the price of scabbards lined with lead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

In Ultimate Equipment, the Description of viridium says:

> A creature carrying a viridium weapon must save every 24 hours or contract leprosy unless the weapon is kept inside an extradimensional space (such as an efficient quiver) or a scabbard lined with lead.

What the heck is the price of a scabbard or quiver lined with lead?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, **no explicit rules for the purchasing of normal scabbards, lead lined or otherwise, are given**, at least in the SRD.  Nonetheless, we can get a fairly precise answer.

An ounce of lead is a costless focus component for the spell [*Lead Plating*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lead-plating) found in *Kobolds of Golarion*.  This means that lead is effectively free, at least in the quantities you need to line a scabbard.  That just leaves the cost of labor if you aren't willing to do the lining yourself.  At this point we have to determine whether a lead-lined scabbard requires a scabbard and lead as raw materials (in which case it costs twice as much as a scabbard does) or whether it requires a scabbard's raw materials (i.e. half a scabbard, in which case the cost is no different than a regular scabbard) to complete.

Assuming you use a normal scabbard, things are still complicated. Scabbards appear to be either free, or possibly included as part of your clothing/weapon/something else, which puts the cost into GM discretion up to twice the cost of the clothes or weapon the scabbard came with.

If your GM is charging you some incredibly unreasonable price for a regular lead-lined scabbard, buy a lead-lined combat scabbard instead, which costs a maximum of 2gp (assuming it's not sharp.  Sharp ones go up to 20 gp in the worst case scenario).

If you happen to be playing with the 3rd party *[Pure Steam Campaign Setting](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/collections/icosa-entertainment-llc/products/pure-steam-campaign-setting)*, there are much more explicit [rules for lead lining stuff](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Lead-Lined) and it is, indeed, free.

If you *are* the GM, **the price should be no different than a normal scabbard**, and thus free if you don't track equipment very closely and less than a silver piece but more than a copper piece if you do.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer One**

I would rule that it is a masterwork scabbard, which is usually what, +50gp for normal equipment? If someone has some viridium I assume they could afford that. Lead is cheap but labor for making an unusual item is not.

**Answer Two**

If you can't find the answer to this, it's probably not worth the time digging it up. Make things up for the lacunae between the rules and the fictional world. You have just spent 1000% more time on this question than an experienced GM does, who just says "+50 gp and it's heavier! Now on to the dungeon..." Not everything mentioned in the game actually has rules listed somewhere for it, and it's not going to be enriching to hunt down every instance of something mentioned.

I know this is a frame challenge, but after reading your many questions on this site I have two main tips.

1. *Keep it simple.* For running your first game, including anything not in the Core Rulebook is basically your rapid path to failure, you need experience with the game without 1000 options and distractions to develop the skills you will need to have.
2. *Don't overthink it.* If you are getting paralyzed with the need for decisions over stuff like this, it's because of rule 1 above. Just make some rulings, see how they work out, and move ahead. By overloading yourself with options and then not having yet developed a GM's eye for what's important and not important and how and when to ad lib, you're avoiding your real chance for improvement, which is real play experience.
3. If you think you need anything else, go back to rules 1 and 2.

Comment: Why would lead lining a scabbard make it masterwork?

Comment: Because that's super unusual custom work, and you want the lining to be made to exact "I want to still have kids someday" specifications - thick enough, no seams or cracks even after repeated use, etc. It's why even just those lead lined aprons they put on you at the dentist cost $200 or so when lead is still $1/lb cheap today.